# Zeromq Pattern for mixture of async and sync communication

Tags: zeromq

My network has one server and possibly thousands of clients. In most cases, the server sends a command to one of the clients and the client immediately sends a response. But there are cases wherein the client initiates the communication to the server, that is the client sends a status update to the server but then does not need to wait for the server's reply.

I am quite new to zeromq, I would like to ask what kind of pattern suits this kind of communication?

Answer (score 0):

I think [The Asynchronous Client/Server Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#header-77) is exactly what you need.